# Sharing SSRS reports with my organization

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016, access-rights

We are currently trying to make use of SSRS within my organization and I want to know how other organizations share these reports with the broader organization without having to give every individual rights to the SQL databases on the SQL server.

We have considered creating Active directory groups and then adding those groups as registered users under the databases but are having push back from IT related to possible data breaches when numerous users have access to a database.

If the groups only have read-only access then I don't know how much extra risk there would be.

What have other organizations done to allow individuals access to data without having to give individual access to each user?

Comment: No rights needed apart from the SSRS user? I use SSRS, it connects using a single domain account, all users can run reports. It also connects to a read-only secondary replica so all the reporting load does not hit the production servers.

Answer (score 0):

There are two levels of permissions here - the permission to access the report and the permission to access the data.

You can setup data sources in SSRS as shared data source - and provide credentials that are stored securely in SSRS to access the data source.  That can be a SQL account or Windows account (with windows account - you may need to set the account that runs SSRS to allow delegation).

When you build your report - setup the report to use a shared data source, the same name as the shared data source created in SSRS and make sure you do not allow overwriting the data sources in your project.  When you then publish the report - the report will be published to use the shared data source and will not overwrite the one that already exists.

Now - you can create your AD groups and use those groups to grant access to the folder/report in SSRS.  The users who have access to the reports will be able to run the reports but will not have direct access to the database system.